# SpeechSynthesisUtterance onmark - working example

Tags: speech-synthesis

I am looking for a working example for the onmark event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/onmark).

I followed the MDN implementation (Chrome 72) but the onmark callback is never called.

I specified well structured SSML as text value with mark tags in place as following:

```
"<?xml version='1.0'?><speak version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd' xml:lang='en-US'> Go from <mark name='here'/> here, to <mark name='there'/> there!</speak>"
```

Would appreciate any examples/ideas.

Thank you,
G

Comment: Hello and welcome. This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: Thank you. Where would you recommend to ask my question?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca From what your linked, it says "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example." OP had given a snippet of code, and explained what they want, the platform to reproduce the error, and ask for debugging. I would consider this question is on-topic as the page you had linked described.